# difference/relation between matrix and vector

Tags: statistics, data-science

What is the difference between vector and metrics , can I say matrix is collection of vector ?
I tried to find the answer in google but could not find accurate answer.

It will be very helpful if you can explain with example.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Vector and matrices are just ways to store information, with very interesting properties.

A vector [1,2,3].
A matrix [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

A vector is like a special and simple case of a matrix.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) has good material.